# Notice: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to int

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, smarty

I can't figure out the error above. Has anyone seen this before. I am using PHP with Smarty and incorporating PDO into my code.

PHP var_dump of code $data `$smarty->assign("results", $data);`

```
 object(PDOStatement)#22 (1) { 
  ["queryString"]=> string(236) "SELECT p.id,p.brag,p.brag_desc,p.brag_id,p.user_id, p.panel_id,p.domainurl,p.type,p.price FROM ruj_users_bg as p left join ruj_users as u on p.user_id=u.id WHERE u.status !=0 and 1 and p.status = 1 GROUP BY p.id DESC LIMIT 0 OFFSET 25" }
```

PHP Error from Smarty template:

Notice: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to int in /var/www/vhosts/somesite.com/httpdocs/templates_c/3d14690fd8419657273a6dce45bbca85dfc1e261.file.bragsdata.tpl.php on line 25

Line 25 from Smarty template:

$_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['smarty']->value['section']['res']['loop'] = is_array($_loop=$_smarty_tpl->getVariable('results')->value) ? count($_loop) : max(0, (int)$_loop); unset($_loop);

Not sure where the problem is here. Your help is very appreciated.

update: Function call with `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

```
 $data = fetchData($limit_start,$page_records);

 function fetchData$limit_start,$page_records){
            $db = Core::getInstance();
            $sql = "SELECT id FROM ruj_users_bg WHERE
                   (type = :type3 OR type = :type4) 
                   AND status =:uno 
                   ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT :lim OFFSET :page";

    $res = $db->dbh->prepare($sql);
            $res->bindValue(':type3',3, PDO::PARAM_INT);                
            $res->bindValue(':type4',4, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $res->bindValue(':uno',1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $res->bindValue(':lim',(int)$limit_start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $res->bindValue(':page',(int)$page_records, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $res->execute();
        $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);       

    return $res;

}
```

Comment: I guess because `is_array()` on a `PDOStatement` gives `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `PDOStatement` is strictly not an array type. It implements `Traversable` though, so I'm surprised that Smarty doesn't accept it as something that can be looped over.

To turn your database results into a standard array, you'd have to use `->fetchAll()`:

```
$smarty->assign('results', $data->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Comment: I just updated my post with the function call that should return fetchAll, but it is not working apparently. Your suggestion did work outside function, but why is that?

Comment: @ClaudeGrecea You should `return $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` from your function.

Comment: That works! You're the Man! Can you recommend a book or website on advance topics on PDO? PHP.net does a poor job of explaining things.

Comment: To be honest, I feel that this is a Smarty issue; it should really support passing in query result objects.

Answer (score -1):

The error message is pretty self-explanatory - `$data` variable contains something different from what you expect.
It seems that you're passing whole PDO object into template, instead of fetching some particular value first.

I'd suggest to play for a while with PDO alone, without Smarty or anything, to get familiar with it and learn how to get desired values.
Or at least check your values with `var_dump()` before assign.